# How to keep the checked state of multiple checkboxes even after leaving the activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, checked, android-checkbox

I really need some help. Even after search for hours and reading topics about the `SharedPreferences` I wasn't able to solve my problem.

I want that the checkboxes (multiple checkboxes!) stay checked/unchecked even if I leave the activity. And if I go back to the original activity, the checkboxes should be in the same status as they were before.
So that you can basically put the app into the background and if you bring it to the foreground again or go to another activity, the checkboxes should still be checked/unchecked (depending on what the user checked).

Here is my Code for the Activity.java:

```
public class TennisActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Variabeln
    CheckBox cb118;
    CheckBox cb119;
    CheckBox cb120;
    CheckBox cb121;
    CheckBox cb122;
    CheckBox cb123;
    CheckBox cb149;
    CheckBox cb150;
    CheckBox cb151;
    CheckBox cb152;
    CheckBox cb153;

    //Going back to menu by pressing back on device
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //super.onBackPressed();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(TennisActivity.this, SportActivity.class);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tennis);

        //Variabeln initalisiern
        cb118 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox118);
        cb119 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox119);
        cb120 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox120);
        cb121 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox121);
        cb122 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox122);
        cb123 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox123);
        cb149 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox149);
        cb150 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox150);
        cb151 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox151);
        cb152 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox152);
        cb153 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox153);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) to save the current state when a user toggles a checkbox. You can reload the data from it once you get to `onCreate` again.

To get shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = 
getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_APPLICATIONS_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To write:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("MY_BOOL_VARIABLE_KEY", myBoolVariable);
editor.commit();
```

To read:

```
myBoolVariable = sharedPref.getBoolean("MY_BOOL_VARIABLE_KEY", defaultValue);
```

For you particular case, you will need a key to identify each one of you checkboxes something like this:

```
private static final String cb118Key = "cb118_key";
```

Then after you initialize the checkboxes, you should set their state according to what was saved on the `SharedPreferences`:

```
cb118Checked = sharedPref.getBoolean(cb118Key, defaultValue);
cb118.setChecked(cb118Key);
```

The only thing missing is to save the new state when the user changes the checkbox state:

```
cb118.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        editor.putBoolean(cb118Key, isChecked);
        editor.commit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey Natan, I am pretty new to Android Studio. Can you explain me where exactly I have to write those SharedPreferences in?

Comment: Yes I'll do that - I'm still trying to figure it out though! :)

Comment: In which method do I put those SharedPreferences codes in? Do I have to make this all into the onCreate-Methode? 
It seems to work now, the activity remembers the checked one. However the app closes if I check it, but if I reopen it the checkbox remains checked (as I wanted). 
Is there a possibility to write you privately? :)

Comment: All of that code should be called after `onCreate()`, ideally you should break it down into smaller methods like `loadInitialValues()` or `setupCheckedChangedListeners()`. You can have more info about the error you are having if you take a look on Android Studio's logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Store a flag in shared preference and check value. If its true then set checked like below code.

```
String notif = pref.getString("notification", null);
if (notif != null && notif.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                checkBoxNotification.setChecked(true);

            }

checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (checkBoxn.isChecked()) {
                        notification = "true";
                        editor.putString("notification", notification).commit();

                    } else {
                        notification = "false";
                        editor.putString("notification", notification).commit();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Natan, here is the solution:
*(Note that there are some imports to -- usually automatically -- have to be added such as java.util.HashMap)*

```
//Variabeln
CheckBox cb118;
CheckBox cb119;
CheckBox cb120;
CheckBox cb121;
CheckBox cb122;
CheckBox cb123;
CheckBox cb149;
CheckBox cb150;
CheckBox cb151;
CheckBox cb152;
CheckBox cb153;
//TRY
boolean myBoolVariable = false;
private static final String cb118Key = "cb118_key";
private static final String cb119Key = "cb119_key";
private static final String cb120Key = "cb120_key";
private static final String cb121Key = "cb121_key";
private static final String cb122Key = "cb122_key";
private static final String cb123Key = "cb123_key";
private static final String cb149Key = "cb149_key";
private static final String cb150Key = "cb150_key";
private static final String cb151Key = "cb151_key";
private static final String cb152Key = "cb152_key";
private static final String cb153Key = "cb153_key";

SharedPreferences sharedPref = null;


//Zurück zu SportActivity
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(TennisActivity.this, SportActivity.class);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 1);

}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_tennis);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    //Variabeln initalisiern
    cb118 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox118);
    cb119 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox119);
    cb120 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox120);
    cb121 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox121);
    cb122 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox122);
    cb123 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox123);
    cb149 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox149);
    cb150 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox150);
    cb151 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox151);
    cb152 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox152);
    cb153 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox153);

    sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("alessionegrini.checkliste", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // I'll turn that into a map so it's easy to iterate over the values
    Map<String, CheckBox> checkboxMap = new HashMap();
    checkboxMap.put(cb118Key, cb118);
    checkboxMap.put(cb119Key, cb119);
    checkboxMap.put(cb120Key, cb120);
    checkboxMap.put(cb121Key, cb121);
    checkboxMap.put(cb122Key, cb122);
    checkboxMap.put(cb123Key, cb123);
    checkboxMap.put(cb149Key, cb149);
    checkboxMap.put(cb150Key, cb150);
    checkboxMap.put(cb151Key, cb151);
    checkboxMap.put(cb152Key, cb152);
    checkboxMap.put(cb153Key, cb153);

    loadInitialValues(checkboxMap);
    setupCheckedChangeListener(checkboxMap);
}

public void loadInitialValues(Map<String, CheckBox> checkboxMap) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, CheckBox> checkboxEntry: checkboxMap.entrySet()) {
        Boolean checked = sharedPref.getBoolean(checkboxEntry.getKey(), false);
        checkboxEntry.getValue().setChecked(checked);
    }
}

public void setupCheckedChangeListener(Map<String, CheckBox> checkboxMap) {
    for (final Map.Entry<String, CheckBox> checkboxEntry: checkboxMap.entrySet()) {
        checkboxEntry.getValue().setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(checkboxEntry.getKey(), isChecked);
                editor.apply();
            }
        });
    }
}}
```